# onClick of both child and parent triggered when child is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Sample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChild = this.handleChild.bind(this);
    this.handleParent = this.handleParent.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{width: '100%', height: '500px', background: 'white'}}
        onClick={this.handleParent}>

        <div
          style={{ width: '40px', height: '40px', margin: '0 auto', background: 'black'}}
          onClick={this.handleChild}>
          hello
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }

  handleParent(e) {
    console.log('parent');
  }

  handleChild(e) {
    console.log('child');
  }
}
```

output when child is clicked

```
child
parent
```

desire output is

```
child
```

I mean I just want to trigger only child's onClick when child is clicked.

Parent is working fine. It triggers only parent's onClick when parent is clicked.
The problem I'm having is with child.

Comment: `e.stopPropagation();` inside child handler for stopping parent event

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need stop *propagation* inside child handler,

```
handleChild(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('child');
}
```

> [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) - Prevents further propagation of the current event in
>   the capturing and bubbling phases.

```js
class Sample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChild = this.handleChild.bind(this);
    this.handleParent = this.handleParent.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{width: '100%', height: '500px', background: 'white'}}
        onClick={this.handleParent}>

        <div
          style={{ width: '40px', height: '40px', margin: '0 auto', background: 'black'}}
          onClick={this.handleChild}>
          hello
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }

  handleParent(e) {
    console.log('parent');
  }

  handleChild(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('child');
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Sample />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```